# heroku local malfunctions versus heroku cloud deployed App

Tags: maven, heroku

I have a java webapp on heroku. It runs perfectly on the cloud. But when run locally it appears to use a stale resource. My jar is called nymmbl1-1.0.jar. I have 100% verified the resource is correct in target\nymmbl1-1.0.jar and ~.m2\repository\com\nymmbl\nymmbl1\1.0\nymmbl1-1.0.jar. When run locally the resource is old. It's as though heroku local is using some cached version.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this?

The out-of-date resource is a local read-only SQlite database. When running "heroku local" the database is accessed but the content returned is different than the actual database content in the current jar. The content returned is from an older version of the SQLite DB that is not in the current JAR.

As I said, this problem is not observed when run on the cloud.

My guess is that "heroku local" is doing something I don't expect. Can you suggest what may be the problem or how to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem disappeared upon updating some maven artifacts. For the record here's what I changed:

> org.springframework.boot  spring-boot-starter-parent, changed from
>   1.5.2.RELEASE to 1.5.7.RELEASE
>
> webjars-bootstrap.version, from 3.3.6 to 3.3.7-1
>
> webjars-jquery-ui.version 1.1.14 => 1.12.1
>
> webjars-jquery.version 2.2.4 => 3.2.1
>
> thymeleaf.version 3.2.5.RELEASE => 3.0.7.RELEASE